# create multiple folders in python automatically

Tags: python, file, creation

I want to create a path like `C:\sample\sample1\hello.py`.  It should automatically create the complete path from `sample` to `hello.py`, and all the directories in between.  Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 6):

The following functions may help:

- [os.makedirs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs)
- [os.path.dirname](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)
- [os.path.basename](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
root_path = 'C:\path'

folders = ['folder 01', 'folder 02', 'folder 03']

for folder in folders:

    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, folder))
```